# downgrade xcode version from 4.2.1 to 4.2

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5, osx-lion

I am using xcode 4.2.1 , iOS 5 lion 10.7 versions. I want to downgrade the current version of xcode from 4.2.1 to 4.2. Please guide me to do that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: uninstall xcode 4.2.1 and download xcode 4.2 and install...! and remove xcode following command: sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all

Comment: Why would you want to do this, I wonder ?

Comment: Hi, Dinesh..I tried it and worked greatly. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Hi Paul, actually I just want to do some testing in 4.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install multiple versions at the same time in different directories. If You want to get rid of a version, you will have to delete the /Developer directory and re-install your target version in that directory.

There's not much of a difference in 4.2 and 4.2.1 by the way.

Comment: Hi roronoa zorro, Thanks for the valuable reply.. :)